# In one figure, different curve, different xlim

Tags: r

I would like to set different xlim for different curve, for example

curve1:

```
geom_line(aes(y = y1, colour = "y1"))+  xlim(1,3)
```

curve2:

```
geom_line(aes(y = y2, colour = "y2"))+  xlim(4,7)
```

curve3:

```
geom_line(aes(y = y3, colour = "y3"))+  xlim(7,10)
```

But in one figure,

```
library("ggplot2")

 x <- 1:10
 y1 <- a+1
 y2 <- a+2
 y3 <- a+3

mm <- data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3)

ggplot(mm, aes(x=x) ) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y1, colour = "y1"))+  
  geom_line(aes(y = y2, colour = "y2"))+  
  geom_line(aes(y = y3, colour = "y3"))+  
  xlab("x") + 
  ylab("y")
```

how to achieve this figure ?[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP5L6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can subset the data according to the limits you want for each geom:

```
x <- 1:10
y1 <- x+1
y2 <- x+2
y3 <- x+3

mm <- data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=mm[which(mm$x>=1 & mm$x<=3),], aes(x=x, y = y1, colour = "y1")) +  
  geom_line(data=mm[which(mm$x>=4 & mm$x<=7),], aes(x=x, y = y2, colour = "y2")) +  
  geom_line(data=mm[which(mm$x>=7 & mm$x<=10),], aes(x=x, y = y3, colour = "y3")) +  
  xlab("x") + 
  ylab("y")
```

[image]

Comment: @perlatex did this answer solve your question? If so please consider recognising the help that people offer you by up voting answers that help, and clicking on the green arrow to select the best answer that solved your problem. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
library("ggplot2")

a <- 1:10 #rnorm(10)
x <- 1:10
y1 <- a+1
y2 <- a+2
y3 <- a+3

mm <- data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3)
mm[mm$x > 3, ]$y1 <- NA
mm[mm$x < 4 | mm$x > 7, ]$y2 <- NA
mm[mm$x < 7, ]$y3 <- NA

ggplot(mm, aes(x=x) ) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y1, colour = "y1"))+  
  geom_line(aes(y = y2, colour = "y2"))+  
  geom_line(aes(y = y3, colour = "y3"))+  
  xlab("x") + 
  ylab("y")
```

[image]

Comment: But this actually deletes data, rather than just omits it from the plot. Not sure that is what OP wants.

Comment: but you already have the data as y1, y2, y3 vectors, it's only in the dataframe where you are masking the data that you dont need.

Comment: @dww  you are strict